Azure Notification Hubs Android Client SDK - FCM V1 Upgrade
Re-submitted & Updated this question as:
"Azure Notification Hubs Android FCMv1 Client SDK - FcmV1TemplateRegistration - No Payload"
Need to create FcmV1TemplateRegistration and FcmV1RegistrationId so updated to 2.0.0
com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:2.0.0
Call to registerTemplate on device now creates FcmV1TemplateRegistration in Azure Hub
(Get Android device regid with FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken() function first)
   String messageTemplate = "{\"message\":{\"android\":{\"data\":{\"msgtext\":\"$(msgtext)\",\"msgsndr\":\"$(msgsndr)\"}}}}";
   String RegistrationTagTopic = "5050";
   mobile_RegistrationId = hub.registerTemplate(regid, "CAREV1", messageTemplate, RegistrationTagTopic).getRegistrationId();

Example registration: mobile_RegistrationId returned above is Notification Hub RegistrationId
<ETag>5</ETag>
<ExpirationTime>2124-06-12T05:55:24.1941413Z</ExpirationTime>
<RegistrationId>2837404...516-2</RegistrationId>
<Tags>5050</Tags>
<FcmV1RegistrationId>eZMPxd2pQBi...Uh</FcmV1RegistrationId>
<BodyTemplate><![CDATA[{"message":{"android":{"data":{"msgtext":"$(msgtext)","msgsndr":"$(msgsndr)"}}}}]]></BodyTemplate>
<TemplateName>CAREV1</TemplateName>
</FcmV1TemplateRegistrationDescription>

It seems the format of the template in the App for FCMv1 is absolutely critical because my App threw an exception on register with any other format than {"message":{"android":{"data":{...}}}}
Send to device tag 5050 using Azure Notification Hubs REST API Method (same API call we've used successfully since 2015 presuming you know how to generate your Authorization token): Send a template notification with parameters like;
   ServiceBusNotification-Format = "template"
   ServiceBusNotification-Tags = "5050"
   ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8."
   Method = "POST"
   URI = "https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{NotificationHub}/messages/?api-version=2015-01"

Example of JSON posted in the call
{"message":{"android":{"data":{"msgtext":"My short message","msgsndr":"ADMIN"}}}}

Notification is received on the device fine, but there is no payload
Send (POST) same message direct to 5050 via FCM/JWT routine, slightly different JSON format;
{"message":{"topic":"5050","data":{"msgtext":"My short message","msgsndr":"ADMIN"},"android":{"priority":"high"},"fcm_options":{"analytics_label":"xyz"}}}

Notification and message payload are perfect (note extra FCM parameters) and works every time. Of course, FCM doesn't require a template in the App itself or the server process.
Question: What's going wrong with my template send via Notification Hubs..?

Were you able to figure this out? I've updated my sdk to 2.0.0 and am no longer receiving push notifications.

@Zachary Bell Not really. I raised the question on MS Learn and they confirmed that the SDK should register FCMv1 but I tried it briefly and it crashed. Now I'm stumped whether we have to do anything because they post this:: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-notification-hubs-and-google-s-firebase-cloud-messaging-migration/

Oh, according to email blitz entitled "Support of Azure Notification Hubs’ Firebase Cloud Messaging legacy API will be retired by 20 June 2024" it looks like we do..!
